# ActionClient in Rosjava

Tags: ros, navigation, actionlib, simpleactionclient, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I read that actionlib isn't yet supported with the latest release of rosjava. Is there an alternative to specify, using code and not rviz, a target location to a base that is running tha navigation stack?
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40613/actionclient-in-rosjava/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could always write a small proxy in another language that supports actionlib. For example: https://code.google.com/p/parsec/source/browse/#hg%2Fnavigation_waypoints_server

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2